# prepare function cause crash

Tags: ios, swift

In my swift app I've the following prepare function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let destination = segue.destination as? LocalPictureCVC {
        destination.selectedLocal = selectedLocal
    }
}
```

But when I try to use selectedLocal in LocalPictureCVC it crash due to selectedLocal is nil.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what type of selectedLocal ??

Comment: of type Local a custom class, but is it important?

Comment: You test that it is not nil before assigning it to `destination.selectedLocal`?

Comment: is it connected to ib ??

Comment: yes I test it and also it's connected to nib with 'show' segue.

Comment: How is defined `selectedLocal` in `LocalPictureCVC`? When you do `destination.selectedLocal = selectedLocal`, is `selectedLocal` nil?

Comment: first of all, try to run by commenting out `destination.selectedLocal = selectedLocal`, so that you know something else is not wrong.

Comment: I recommend to force unwrap `segue.destination as! LocalPictureCVC`. It must not crash. If it does you made a **design** mistake for example having forgotten to assign the custom class in Interface Builder.

Comment: Maybe look in the LocalPictureCVC code so that you don't initialise the attribute to nil somewhere like in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I try to perform a segue by touch gesture over header view of tableview controller. but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Try this I hope it will help you:-

first make sure to give segue properly with identifier then code like below
then in first ViewController

```
var valueToPassInSecondVC = ""

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    //NOTE:- make sure about your identifier is correct as well as destination ViewController
    if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifierOfSegue" {
        let destVC = segue.destination as! ContainerViewController
        destVC.valueFromFirstVC = self.valueToPassInSecondVC
    }
}
```

in your destination class

```
var valueFromFirstVC:String = ""
//In my case pass String from FirstViewController to SecondViewController
```

thanks,I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try checking your segue identifier in your prepare function

```
if segue.identifier == "Something"
```